# Deploy ReactJS app in in development environment with proxy

Tags: javascript, rest, reactjs, proxy, react-redux

I have been using **React** over a month and in our project we are running API service calls in different **port(81)** and web in another **port(80)**.

In my local development environment I am able to use proxy to make **API calls** and **it works**.

example:  **"proxy": "http://localhost:8081" in my package.json **

Just wanted to know how does one can make this work when we deploy it to staging or other environment, other than local environment.

fyi, I get 404 when I make service or API calls in development environment.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: so you get a 404 in dev environment but at the same time it works on your dev environment?

Answer (score 0):

Bundle your React-project for production and let it be served static from the server so everything will be served from the same port, no issues.

Comment: Could you guide me some tutorial or link on the same? because I am not able to run the app. Getting 'You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.'